# Read C# UploadString request with PHP and respond

Tags: c#, php

I need a PHP solution to return the correct server-response to the code below, for debugging purposes, due to missing source-code documentation. Any directions appreciated. All i need is a PHP script to "answer" with what this part of code is waiting for to assume i am logged in to the dummy web service. Thanks.

```
json = string.Format("{{\"name\":\"{0}\",\"pw\":\"{1}\"}}", usertext, pwtext);
                            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
                            result = client.UploadString(UrlBase.urlBase + "Login.php", json);
                            if (result.Contains(usertext) && result.Contains(pwtext) && result.Contains("\"id\""))
                            {
                                textError.Text = "You are logged in";
                                SaveID(result);

                            }
```

EDIT - My current try in PHP:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    echo $data;
}
?>
```

Comment: Well boi we ain't doing that for you.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes what's the problem again?

Comment: You didn't even try anything, brother. Start making the php code, if you get any trouble there, come back at us. But don't expect us to give you stuff.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes do you have any psychic abilities or something? I AM trying to achieve it, but i get a bunch of **** that's why i am asking for help in here. Let me edit the question tho, to let you see it. Sorry for being rude but i am pulling my hair for over an hour for this.

Comment: No, I wish I did though. But if you have PHP code which is causing you trouble, just add it here.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes added it just now. Thanks again.

Comment: You're missing the interrogation in `<php`

Comment: @PhiterFernandes i added the PHP script without the tags and added the tags manually (without copy-pasting them). In my source it's alright but i still can't get the response i need.